# Find lines in multiple files starting with text, and replacing with lowercase

Tags: unix, sed, text-processing, lowercase

I'm trying to find all files that contains lines that start with a specific string, and then set everything in that line after that to lowercase. I'm able to do parts of what I want but can't seem to figure out how to get it all to work.

Here's an example of the string I'm looking for:

```
      _assetBundleName: SomeDirectory/ChildDirectory
```

and I need it to be:

```
      _assetBundleName: somedirectory/childdirectory
```

So I can't convert the entire line to lower case, just everything after the string I'm looking for (which is `_assetBundleName:` ). And I need to perform this on many files (all directories and subdirectories from where the command is run).

`sed 's/[a-z]/\L&/g'` converts everything to lowercase, not just everything after the string I've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `gnu-sed` with 2 capture groups:

```sh
sed -E 's/(_assetBundleName:)(.*)/\1\L\2/' file
```

`\L\2` will lowercase only the 2nd capture group content.

---

As noted above that this requires `gnu-sed`. If you don't have that then you can use this `awk` command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"} 
$1 ~ /_assetBundleName/ {$2 = tolower($2)} 1' file
```

Comment: That would also replace lines that start with `xxx_assetBundleName:`, for example.
So `^` might be better to have.

Comment: When running this against `_assetBundleName: SomeDirectory/ChildDirectory` I'm getting this: `_assetBundleName:L SomeDirectory/ChildDirectory`.

Comment: Maybe it's my version of sed/awk that's the issue? I'm on MacOS. Using the awk command you provided, it ends up having no effect. EDIT: It looks like it's the spacing prior to the line that's causing the issue, if I remove the leading whitespaces it's working with awk.

Comment: Still no luck with the updated version, it's only working if there's no leading whitespaces.

Comment: Since you wrote `sed 's/[a-z]/\L&/g' converts everything to lowercase` it gave an impression that you already have `gnu-sed` otherwise `awk` would have been my first answer

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/_assetBundleName:/s/:.*/\L&/' input_file
```

or

```
$ sed "/_assetBundleName:/s/\(.*\)\(:.*\)/echo '\1'\$(echo \\2 | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')/" file | bash
```

**Output**

```
 _assetBundleName: somedirectory/childdirectory
```

Comment: When running it against a file with `_assetBundleName: SomeDirectory/ChildDirectory`, I end up with `_assetBundleNameL: SomeDirectory/ChildDirectory`

Comment: @NicFoster @NicFoster How about this `sed "/_assetBundleName:/s/\(.*\)\(:.*\)/echo '\1'\$(echo \\2 | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')/" file | bash`

Comment: That one works!

Comment: Awesome @NicFoster! I will update my answer with this solution also

Comment: 1. This sed will give error for all the non matching lines. 2. Unquoted string in `echo` is subject to shell expansion.

Comment: @anubhava As you are aware, the second solution was a response to GNU not being available. My initial solution has none of the issues you have mentioned, but, thanks for the tip. It is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A Perl solution:

```
perl -i -pe 's{(_assetBundleName:)(.*)}{$1\L$2}' file1 file2 ...
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file).
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

`s{PATTERN}{REPLACEMENT}` : replace `PATTERN` with `REPLACEMENT`.
`.*` : any character, repeated 0 or more times.
`$1, $2`: first and second capture groups, captured with parentheses.
`\L$2` : lowercase everything in the second capture group.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)